# Windows Simulate clicks in a program

Tags: windows, forms, click, simulate

I'd like to create a program which format signature in Outlook 2007.

The user will only have to lauch Outlook. It will search informations about the user, then will create automatically the signature.
The user wouldn't have to open any menu, the program will do it for him.

I'd like to know what language will be easy to use to create this kind of program ?

Thank you

Comment: [AutoIt scripting](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is great for simulating clicks on Windows apps (and more)... but I agree with @PocketUniverse that you shouldn't have to do that when there are better alternatives provided in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you shouldn't be simulating clicks, instead you should just generate an automated signature file which the user could then load.

Edit:

The file formats for windows signatures are`.txt`, `.htm` and `.rtf`. All of these are very well documented formats and should be easy to generate. They should be saved in `c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`. Outlook saves each signature in all three formats, presumably for portability to other apps and individual email settings (for instance if the user uses `HTML` or not).

Comment: okay. But when i generated myself the .htm, .txt, and the rtf, i can't see them in the listbox where signatures are. Maybe should we modify a config file ? but where ? I didn't find it

Comment: I've just tried this in Windows 7 with Outlook 2010 and it works fine. You do however need to have all three files. They all need to have the same filename (except for the file endings) and they obviously need to be in the correct user's folder.